# Let zip read source file list from a file

Tags: zip

For example,

```
zip -r output.zip file1 file2 file3
```

I need to put the file list "file1 file2 file3" into a text file "input_list.txt", then use the command like:

```
zip -r output.zip -input input_list.txt
```

After zip -help, the only relative information it gave is this:

```
-@ read names from stdin
```

So I tried:

```
'cat input_list.txt'>'zip -r -@ output.zip'
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can compress multiples files listed in a list text file
As you understood, the `-@` option reads the source files names from stdin
So, simply redirect the list to the zip program stdin

```
zip output.zip -@ < files.list
```

note that `-r` is required if the `files.list` contains directories

Comment: Do you know why files.list should put each file in a line, instead of split them with space?

Comment: @jw_ filenames can contain spaces

Comment: But generally it is quoted to escape spaces. For example, rsp files in compilation command line are all single line that contains all the source file names splitted by space.

Comment: @jw_ no quotes needed here